# How to read same kafka message at multiple Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I am very new to Kakfa Spring integration. I have implemented the Kafka message sending and One Listener and it working fine for me. But I want to Listener same message at two place. Can any one help me. Below is my code.

```
 spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-commit-interval=100
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=true
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=sample-group


spring.kafka.producer.batch-size= 16384
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.retries= 0
spring.kafka.producer.buffer-memory=33554432

spring.kafka.template.default-topic=spring-topic
```

Sender Code:

```
public void testSimple() {
        System.out.println("Sending Topic Here");
        template.send("spring-topic", 0, "foo");
        template.flush();
    }
```

Receiver:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "spring-topic")
    public void listen1(String foo) {
        System.out.println("Got Notification Here");
        this.latch1.countDown();
    }
```

Can any help me how to read same message at different place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the consumer group in this line:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=sample-group
```

to something else in the second consumer it will get all messages as well.

[This article](https://www.opsclarity.com/understanding-kafka-consumer-lag/) explains a bit more about consumer groups and is worth a read.